# How does Django offer code completion for Query.filter method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, code-completion

If I have a Django model like:

```python
class Example(models.Model):
    is_in_stackoverflow = models.BooleanField()
```

and I try to filter said model like:

```python
Example.objects.filter(is_in_stackoverflow=True)
```

My IDE (Pycharm to be specific) knows to offer me other kwargs based on the fields I specific for my model (for this case it might offer me `is_in_stackoverlow__in` or `is_in_stackoverlow__isnull`)

I would like to replicate this functionality in a library I am writing. I tried looking into the django source code but was unable to figure this magic out.

Comment: This is just PyCharm's Django plugin that reasons about the filtering syntax, it does not "understand" the `.filter(...)` method, it simply has implemented the documentation on filtering, such that it can offer these as candidates.

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing... damn

Answer (score 0):

As helpfully mentioned by Willem Van Onsem, This is done by Pycharm's Django plugin.